# I'm trying to clone a git repository but it shows a proxy error

Tags: javascript, git

while trying to clone a git repository , I'm facing this error.

> Cloning into 'homework-0-rach24'... fatal: unable to access
>   'https://github.com/rach24/homework-0-rach24.git/': Could not resolve
>   proxy: proxy.iiit.ac.in

Comment: put error message in quote

Answer (score 0):

This is because your are behind the proxy server 
Set the proxy settings like this

```
git config --global http.proxy http://<username>:<password>@<proxy-server-url>:<port>
```

Or in simplest case this may also work

```
git config --global http.proxy <proxy server IP>:<port>
```

For https

```
git config --global https.proxy <proxy server ip>:<port>
```